How to use DAX to filter rows based on a date slicer
I'm new to PBI and DAX
I've inherited a PBI report that uses the MS timeline slicer custom visual.

The problem I'm trying to resolve is to only show data in a table where any period inside the date/date range selected falls within the StartDate and EndDate of a table of data.
Based on the following subset table of data...


If February 2024 was selected in the Timeline Slicer than only rows
with Id 1 would be shown.

If July 2024 was selected in the Timeline Slicer than only rows with Id 3 would be shown.

If September 2024 to January 2025 was selected in the Timeline Slicer than only rows with Id 4 would be shown.

If January 2025 was selected in the Timeline Slicer than no rows would be shown.


Including a 1-2-many relationship between the Calendar and Data table isn't going to work here.
I'm thinking the way to do would be to have two measures.
One that will hold the value of the MIN date selected, and another to hold the MAX date selected.
SelectedMinDate = DATEVALUE(MIN('Calendar'[Date]))
SelectedMaxDate = DATEVALUE(MAX('Calendar'[Date]))
And then use this in a computed column to filter out the data.
But that's as far as I got.
What do I need further?
This is the DDL for the sample data set
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Test1 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test1
(
    Id          INT IDENTITY(1,1) ,
    Activity    VARCHAR(255) ,
    StartDate   DATE ,
    EndDate     DATE 
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Test1 
    (Activity,StartDate,EndDate)
SELECT 
    T.Activity, 
    T.StartDate ,
    T.EndDate 
FROM (VALUES('Test1', '20240101', '20240430'),
            ('Test2', '20240301', '20240630'),
            ('Test3', '20240501', '20241031'),
            ('Test4', '20241101', '20241231')
      ) T(Activity,StartDate,EndDate)


can you post an image of your data model with all relevant tables and relations?

It really is only two tables. One for the Calendar and the other with the data (Test1).
The 1-2-many relationship between the Calendar(date) and Data(StartDate)

Is your test data correct as it doesn't match your expected results

I've corrected the expected results

I think your test data has some errors in so I will assume you mean what I think. Here is a simple solution.
Table:

Date
Date = CALENDARAUTO()


No relationships.

Measure:
Measure = 
VAR x = VALUES('Date'[Date]) 
VAR y = CALENDAR(MIN('Table'[StartDate]), MAX('Table'[EndDate]))
RETURN 
COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(x,y))

Table visual

Filter pane:

Working:

Be aware of arbitrary shaped sets with this type of date analysis (not needed in this example but possible elsewhere in your analysis).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bGVLguWf4Ls&t=1s

Can you explain what you mean by "arbitrary shaped sets"?

You're best watching the video but it is essentially having a filter over Nov,Dec 2021 and Jan/Feb 2022. Be careful removing filters as you may end up with Nov,Dec,Jan,Feb 2021 inadvertently.
